# Angular JS Error: $injector:nomod Module Unavailable during routing

Tags: javascript, angularjs

So, I am really new to angular JS and I'm working on a project for a company with a team from my school as an internship. I have to get the routing working first though, and it just will not work no matter what I have tried. I tried it with angular JS 1.0.7 and with that I could get it to work, but with the newest version (1.5.7) I just can't after many many hours of trying. This is the error the console currently gives me:

Error: $injector:nomod
Module Unavailable Module 'app' is not available! You either misspelled the module name or forgot to load it. If registering a module ensure that you specify the dependencies as the second argument. The error originates from the  line in index.html as far as I know, since the error disappears if i remove it, but the routing doesn't work then either.

I'd really appreciate any help with this. I know I probably missed something incredibly basic (and the code is probably pretty sloppy), but I just can't figure it out. Oh and by the way, I tried putting the content from app.js to index .html inside script tags and then it didn't give the error, but didn't display anything either, really weird. I have also tried many different ways to do routing as instructed by different tutorials or guides, but I still can't get it to work.

Code:
Index.html (modified so as to not give way the name of the company etc.)

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <link href="css/bootstrap.css" rel="stylesheet">
  <link href="css/ui-bootstrap-1.3.3-csp.css" rel="stylesheet">
  <link href="css/main.css" rel="stylesheet">
  <script src="js/angular.min.js"></script>
  <script src="js/angular-resource.min.js"></script>
  <script src="js/angular-route.min.js"></script>
  <script src="js/ui-bootstrap-1.3.3.min.js"></script> 
  <script src="js/angular-animate.min.js"></script>
  <script src="js/angular-touch.min.js"></script>
  <script src="app/app.js"></script>
  <script src="app/ctrl.js"></script>
  <script src="scripts/routing.js"></script>

</head>
<body>
<div class="navbar navbar-default" id="navbar">
  <div class="container" id="navbar-container">
    <div class="navbar-header">
      <a href="" class="navbar-brand">
        <small>
          <i class="glyphicon glyphicon-log-out"></i>
          Products and Company Info
        </small>
      </a><!-- /.brand -->

    </div><!-- /.navbar-header -->
    <div class="navbar-header pull-right" role="navigation">
      <a href="#howto" class="btn btn-sm btn-warning nav-button-margin"> <i class="glyphicon glyphicon-book"></i>&nbsp;Howto</a>
      <a href="#" class="btn btn-sm btn-warning nav-button-margin"> <i class="glyphicon glyphicon-home"></i>&nbsp;Home</a>
    </div>
  </div><!-- /.navbar-container -->
</div><!-- /.navbar -->

<div>
  <div class="container">
   <div ng-app="app">
    <h2>App name</h2>
    <br/>
    <div ng-view></div>
   </div>
  </div><!-- /.container -->
</div>


</body>
</html>
```

Code app.js:

```
var app = angular.module('mainApp', ['ngResource', 'ngRoute']);
app.run(function($rootScope) {

});
```

Code ctrl.js

```
app.controller("mainCtrl", function($scope) {
    $scope.firstName = "first name";
    $scope.lastName = "last name";
});

app.controller('howtoCtrl', function($scope) {
    $scope.message = 'How To guide here';   
});
```

Code routing.js:

```
// configure our routes
    app.config(function($routeProvider) {
        $routeProvider

        // route for the home page
        .when('/', {
            templateUrl : 'home.html',
            controller  : 'mainCtrl'
        })

        // route for the how to page
        .when('/howto', {
            templateUrl : 'howto.html',
            controller  : 'howtoCtrl'
        })

        // route for the test2 page
        .when('/testi2', {
            templateUrl : 'test2.html',
            controller  : 'test2Controller'
        });
    });
```

Edit: After changing ng-app="app" to ng-app="mainApp", I got the following errors

angular.min.js:103 GET http://localhost/var/www/html/byow_routing_sahlays_2/byow/home.html 404 (Not Found)(anonymous function) @ angular.min.js:103n @ angular.min.js:98g @ angular.min.js:95(anonymous function) @ angular.min.js:130$eval @ angular.min.js:145$digest @ angular.min.js:142$apply @ angular.min.js:145(anonymous function) @ angular.min.js:20invoke @ angular.min.js:41c @ angular.min.js:20Bc @ angular.min.js:21ge @ angular.min.js:19(anonymous function) @ angular.min.js:315b @ angular.min.js:189Sf @ angular.min.js:37d @ angular.min.js:36
angular.min.js:117 Error: [$compile:tpload] http://errors.angularjs.org/1.5.7/$compile/tpload?p0=home.html&p1=404&p2=Not%20Found
    at Error (native)
    at http://localhost/var/www/html/byow_routing_sahlays_2/byow/js/angular.min.js:6:412
    at http://localhost/var/www/html/byow_routing_sahlays_2/byow/js/angular.min.js:156:281
    at http://localhost/var/www/html/byow_routing_sahlays_2/byow/js/angular.min.js:130:409
    at m.$eval (http://localhost/var/www/html/byow_routing_sahlays_2/byow/js/angular.min.js:145:107)
    at m.$digest (http://localhost/var/www/html/byow_routing_sahlays_2/byow/js/angular.min.js:142:173)
    at m.$apply (http://localhost/var/www/html/byow_routing_sahlays_2/byow/js/angular.min.js:145:401)
    at l (http://localhost/var/www/html/byow_routing_sahlays_2/byow/js/angular.min.js:97:250)
    at K (http://localhost/var/www/html/byow_routing_sahlays_2/byow/js/angular.min.js:101:373)
    at XMLHttpRequest.y.onload (http://localhost/var/www/html/byow_routing_sahlays_2/byow/js/angular.min.js:102:397)

Final Edit:
Thanks guys, it works now. The problem was first that ng-app="app" should have been ng-app"mainApp", and I forgot to include the folder to the address of the tempaltes in routing.js after I had originally moved the files to their own folder.

Comment: try adding ng-app="mainApp" to your html tag

Comment: I tried that with and without the ng-app="mainApp inside the div tag also, didn't work. Same errors as in the edit in the main post.

Comment: try removing ng-app from the div, and just keep one ng-app="mainApp" in html tag, you can just have one ng-app in one html.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You call in your html `<div ng-app="app">` but your app is named `mainApp`.
Try to change `<div ng-app="app">` to `<div ng-app="mainApp">`

Comment: Weird, last time I tried that it changed nothing except that the error went away (but nothing worked either) this time I got the following errors by changing that:

Comment: After looking at your error, it seems that the app just can't find your `home.html` in the folder `/var/www/html/byow_routing_sahlays_2/byow/`. Are you sure that home.html is here ? If it can't find it, it can't compile template and render it in `ng-view`.

Comment: Aaah, of course! I forgot to put the templates folder in front of the address for the templates in routing.js It works now so far. I knew it would be some stupid oversight. Thanks to anyone that helped

Answer (score 0):

Add below code to the very first line of `ctrl.js` and `routing.js`

```
var app = angular.module('mainApp');
```

cheers!